# Server Side Event not being received

Tags: python, fastapi, server-sent-events

I've implemented some "real time streaming" to the browser.  This method is using Server Side events, the backend is Python/FastAPI.  I'm developing this primarily on my workstation. Theory of operation is: There are some custom devices on my network that send "heartbeat/health" information.  I pick those up, process them and then send them to the browser (ChartJS).  At the moment, I have 3 devices.  2 of these devices are the same type of device.  I'll call them Device A (qty 1) and Device B  (qty 2).  While the browser is navigated away from one of the real time charts the server backend stores the data for a small period of time. Thus, when you navigate to the real-time graph it automatically fills in using the last 60 seconds of data.

I'm doing this all with Asynchronous Queues.    Device A has it's own Queue, and Devices B have their own Queue.  The packet in the Queue is JSON and the Device ID is inside it.

**On my workstation - everything works as I want it to.**

Then, I move this software over to the device it will live on, which is an ARM device running Linux at about 800Mhz.

Once I get this software loaded and connected I start to check and make sure it works.  Device A is streaming.  If I wait, and check Device A the historic data flushes successfully.

If I go to Device B I see only 1 of the 2 devices data is being received.  If I reload the page, that device may change, it may not.   If I navigate away and come back, BOTH devices history data is populated, but only one is actively showing data. I can refresh (F5) and this may change back and forth.    The amount of data per device is about 100 bytes.

My first thought, was that this was a processing issue.  But flushing the historic data is significantly more data all at once.

Through logging of the js console I see that one of the message is never received.
Using a basic print() statement in python I can see that the message **is** being sent.
Using wireshark I can see the message on the network, and I can also see that the payload is  correct.

I am not sure what else to check.   Some code follows.

Javascript front end (This is truncated, it's too long)

```
        source.onmessage = function (event) {
            /* This line only shows 1 of the 2 packets being received */
            console.log(event.data);
            /* comes over with single quotes, which is not json friendly */          
            var data = event.data.replace(/'/g, '"');
            const json_data = JSON.parse(data);
```

Python side of the SSE: (Variables modified for SO - hopefully no mistakes)

```
@app.get("/data")
async def data():
    async def get_data():
        # clear the queue first, then fill it up
        await interface.empty_queue()
        # this loads the queue with historic data - up to 120 packets of 200 bytes each
        for item in interface.objs.keys():
            await interface.objs[item].load_queue(interface.health_queue, False)
        while True:
            # process the queue
            message = await interface.health_queue.get()
            print(message)
            yield f"data:{message}\n\n"
            interface.health_queue.task_done()
```

Finally, I can see this in wireshark:
Both packets are received on the PC:
[image]

Device 1's payload with the correct ID:
[image]

Device 2's payload with the correct ID:
[image]

However, as I mentioned only one of the IDs is being processes by the browser:

[image]

What I expect it to look like:
[image]

I know this is a lot, and very custom.  But I am hoping someone can help me identify the source of this issue.  This is my first real development with SSE, FastAPI.  But I feel like this is working acceptably when it's not on the target device.